# Custom Android attribute without namespace

Tags: android

I'm making custom [LayoutInflater.Factory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html) and in onCreateView() method I'd like to obtain custom attribute specified for current view. However I don't want to declare styleable for this attribute. I can get this parameter if it was specified in xml attribute for this View using:
    `attrs.getAttributeValue(null, attributeName);`
I can even get it if it was specified in style parameter of the View using:
    `context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{R.attr.custom_attribute);`
However it seems to be impossible to get this attribute if it's specified in theme. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my xml resouces:

```
<style name="CustomTheme"
       parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
     <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextView.Custom</item>
</style>

<style name="TextView.Custom">
    <item name="custom_attribute">"blabla"</item>
</style>
```

P.S. I know I should declare slyleable resource for custom attributes, and it works if I do so, but I want to be sure it is not possible otherwise because it is simplier to use this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnd out you can get it usig this:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textViewStyle, value, true);
typedArray = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(value.resourceId, new int[] {R.attr.custom_attribute});
```